# Select box with background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, canvas

I want to put **selectbox over the background image**.
How can I do that?

In this way, I can offer the user a better experience.

[Background  IMAGE](https://i.hizliresim.com/2XxBuE.png)

[image]

```
<select id='selectbox'>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>50</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, what isnt working? where is your CSS? Simply wrap the image inside a div or use a div with that image as background and then use the selectbox as child of the div.

Comment: There is no css img associated with this form. I don't know how to do it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a div and the image as background image. and insert the select boxes with an absolute positioning.
However this will be a mess for full responsivness and therefor a complete CSS + HTML approach without an image would be way better. For that however you need at least some kind of coding skills.

```css
.select {
  background-image: url(https://i.hizliresim.com/2XxBuE.png);
  width: 419px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

#selectbox_a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 115px;
}

#selectbox_i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 260px;
  top: 115px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select id='selectbox_a'>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
  </select>
  <select id='selectbox_i'>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your  tag inside of a div which have background image and position your select anywhere.

```css
.bg {
  background: url(https://i.hizliresim.com/2XxBuE.png) no-repeat;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
     
#selectbox {
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <select id="selectbox">
    <option>30</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
  </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take soem time to read the SO guidelines. Next time you answer a question, use a parsable code snippet to show your solution and take your time to explain your solution so it can be understood and reproduced by everyone.